# Как инициализировать объект java

Tags: java

Есть класс `Bottle`, в нём создан конструктор `Bottle`, в конструкторе нужно передать созданный внутри конструктора массив в объект `SparklingWater water` для того, чтобы массив использовать в другом классе и методе (в методе `pump`). Как бы я не инициализировал объект - когда компилятор доходит до `water.pump(this.bobbles)` - падает ошибка `"nullPointerException"` из-за того, что `water: null`.

1. Как в данном классе правильно инициализировать объект water?
   2.Нужно ли при создании конструктора `Bottle` указывать параметр `SparklingWater water`?

```
public class Bottle {
    private double volume;
    private SparklingWater water;
    public Bubble[] bobbles;

    public Bottle(double volume) throws InterruptedException {

        Bubble[] bobbles = new Bubble[(int) (volume * 10000)];//заполнилось массивом пузырьков из расчёта объёма
        this.bobbles = bobbles;
        
        //тут проблема
        setWater(water);
        this.water = water;
        water.pump(this.bobbles);
    }
    
    public void open() {
        this.water.setOpened(true);
        //System.out.printf(" Set water statement to 'open' ").println();
    }

    public void warm(int temperature) {
        temperature = 40;
        //System.out.printf(" Warming water to %s", temperature).println();
    }

    public SparklingWater getWater() {
        return  this.water;
        //System.out.printf(" Getting 'Water' object");
    }

    public void setWater(SparklingWater water) {
        this.water = water;
        //System.out.print(" Add new 'water' object ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну при создании объекта Bottle вторым параметром передавайте не null, а экземпляр объекта SparklingWater. Делать и `setWater(water);` и `this.water = water;` не нужно, тут вы просто два раза одно и то же делаете. Делайте что-то одно. 2 - откуда нам знать, вы же не показали класс `SparklingWater`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В конструктор `Bottle` конечно нужно передать объект `SparklingWater water`, если он там используется, иначе откуда этой `water` там взяться? И раз уж среди полей класса есть `volume`, то желательно его тоже инициализировать в конструкторе. Или удалить из списка полей, если он дальше нигде не используется.

```
public Bottle(double volume, SparklingWater water){
        this.volume = volume; // так или удалить из списка полей
        Bubble[] bobbles = new Bubble[(int) (volume * 10000)];
        this.bobbles = bobbles;
        this.water = water;
        water.pump(this.bobbles);
}
```

Тогда, вызывая конструктор `Bottle`, Вам нужно передать два аргумента: `volume` типа `double` и `water` типа `SparklingWater`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Оказалось, что в вызывающем конструктор методе ещё необходимо было создать ссылочную переменную SparklingWater